# How to read Pandas data frame from one file to another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a data from in abc.py i want read  the dataframe(DB) in another file xyz.py and perform some other operation

in xyz.py

**import abc as abc
print(abc.DB)**
its giving empty data frame.

Need a solution how to access a DataFrame in multiple files.

Comment: You shouldn't be importing dataframe in other scripts. Rather have a driver file that uses the function of another file which takes dataframe as a parameter.

Comment: small correction in my question, the second file has threads , and my logic running and inside the thread, I want to use this data frame inside thread from first file.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work by having the following:
`abc.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], ["one", "two", "three"])
```

`xyz.py`:

```
# you could also write "from test import df"
from test import *

print(df)
```

The output I get from running `xyz.py` is this, just as expected:

```
       0  1  2
one    0  0  0
two    1  1  1
three  2  3  4
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Not a good way to do it because it can cause all kinds of memory issues.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've never had a memory issue happening with that, since all it does is run the file itself and get the variables that way. It is also the simplest way that still works (and in my experience, reliably). Am I wrong?

Comment: When you have a large pipeline where data needs to modified numerous times, this approach will hinder the understandability of the code and flow. Sometimes it will also cause weird reference issues like you did not intend to modify a variable but it does.

Comment: small correction in my question, the second file has threads , and my logic running and inside the thread, I want to use this data frame inside thread from first file.